# How do I reset the "Consumer Secret" for my Connected App?

Tags: connected-apps

My Connected App's Consumer Secret has been compromised.  How do I get a new Consumer Secret generated for my app without changing the Consumer Key and/or creating a whole new Connected App?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new app. Because consumer secret is bind with the app you can't change it.

Although you can try one option in the existing app remove outh scope and save it and again edit and create new oAuth so that it will generate new key and secret.

[Reference to create Oauth](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000205876&language=en_US)